# Calculating a column's values based on previous row and a conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to use the following example pseudocode/calculation on a dataframe, where the calculation needs to conditionally use a previous row value. I think I could do this using `apply()`but is there a fast vectorised solution?

```
df['result'] = 1 # init/base value
if df['data'] > 10: 
    df['result'] = df['data'] * 2 - df['result'].shift(1)
else:
    df['result'] = df['result'].shift(1)
```

Comment: Please, provide an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.where`

```py
df['result'] = np.where(df['data'] > 10, df['data'] * 2 - df['result'].shift(1), df['result'].shift(1))
```

Comment: Does this walk through the dataframe in order and sequentially do the calculation on each row? Or is it done in parallel? I see some strange results, almost as if the else condition is calculated too late, meaning the value isn't there for the if clause.

Comment: @biffa It's doesn't do the operation in order, if you want do in order, you'd better use the for loop.